# Default.png no longer exists

Tags: iphone

I've searched for the answer to this question but I can't seem to find it, and logically this process makes no sense to me...

I added a default.png to my app and I didn't like the fact that it didn't show long enough, so I removed it and was going to add a splash screen instead.

The problem is that the default.png still shows on load. I've completely removed it from the Xcode project and from the computer.

I've deleted the installed app from the simulator, and rebuilt the project but it still shows up. I've even exited Xcode and relaunched.  Does this value get saved anywhere that I'm missing?  How do I get rid of this image?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
BWC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing a Clean first? I've had some resources stick around before with Xcode... the clean operation deletes all the build artifacts.